# Как отцентрировать текст по вертикали?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Есть такой код:

html:

```
<p class="hst">Шаблон</p>
```

css:

```
.hst {
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Получается так, что текст наверху рамки, а остальная часть рамки пусто. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как отцентрировать текст по вертикали (не меняя код выше)?

Comment: Дабавьте line-height: 50px

Comment: я боюсь спросить: что значит не меняя код выше?

Comment: т.е. ничего не удалять, а продолжить, добавить код

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `display: table-cell` (разрешить центрирование) в связке с `vertical-align: middle` (выполнить центрирование):

```css
.hst {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;

    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid green;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <p class="hst">Шаблон</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте `line-height: 50px;` - тогда высота строки станет равной высоте вашего блока (`height: 50px;`) и текст отцентрируется:

```css
.hst {
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid green;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p class="hst">Шаблон</p>
```